# How to create immutable set from another immutable set?

Tags: java, set, java-11

Given a set `Set<String> s = Set.of("a", "b", "c")`, how do I create a new immutable set with the contents of `s` and some additional data? I tried `Set t = Set.of(s, "d")`, but this gives me mixed types `t ==> [[a, b, c], d]`. I need `[a, b, c, d]`. I am not using Guava.
thanks!

Comment: `Set<String> r = Stream.of(s, t).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());`

Comment: Note that you cannot get a set that guarantees this order, unless you only use `LinkedHashSet`. `Set.of` is explicit in its iteration order - it's not fixed. `HashSet` has some predictable iteration order but it can change if you add new elements. That means that the result may not be `[a, b, c, d]` but could instead be `[b, d, a, c]` or some other order. I assume you're OK with that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
Set<String> s = Set.of("a", "b", "c");
Set<String> t = Stream.of(s, Set.of("d"))
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
System.out.println(t);
```

output

```
[d, c, b, a]
```

or

```
Set<String> t = Stream.of(s.stream(), Stream.of("d"))
    .flatMap(Function.identity())
    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
```

Comment: another one `Stream.concat(s.stream(), Stream.of("d")).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());`